# How to get array of matches

Tags: c++, boost-regex

I'm trying to do something like in the example of boost::regex_serach in [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html) .

My sample of code is :

```
boost::regex expression("<name=\"[a-zA-z0-9]+\" "
                 "init=\"[0-9]+\"/>");
std::string::const_iterator start, end;
start = Field.begin();
end = Field.end();
boost::smatch what;
boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;
while(regex_search(start, end, what, expression,flags)){
    std::cout<<"@@@" << std::string(what[0].first,what[0].second);
    start = what[0].second;
    // update flags:
    flags |= boost::match_prev_avail;
    flags |= boost::match_not_bob;
}
```

I have some xml file `..... name="SamleName" init="6"/...` And want to have SamlpeName in `what[1]` and init value in `what[2]`, but code listed here only write this field`" name="SamleName" init="6"/"` to `what[0]`.

How can I split this like in regex_search example ??

Comment: I think you may want to mark your expression with subexpressions `<name=\"([a-zA-z0-9]+)\" init=\"([0-9]+)\"/> ` - notice the additional `( )` , via them you can access them in most regex implementation ( dunno for boost actually, but I belive they did that as well )

Answer (score 2):

From a purely regex point of view (I haven't used boost regex library) you need to group the required matches with round brackets `()`. Refer to http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html for more details.

So your regex should be something like this

```
boost::regex expression("<name=(\"[a-zA-z0-9]+\") init=(\"[0-9]+\")/>");
```

You can visualize the matching like this

```
<name=(\"[a-zA-z0-9]+\") init=(\"[0-9]+\")/>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/svOkvVnKZAfehA9K)

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick replay, SOLVED

Comment: @user2597359 If this answers your question I think you should mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about using **boost::sregex_iterator**?